# Trying to display @mentions for a user but my query is spitting out an error

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, pdo

I'm trying to display @mentions for my currently logged in user but I'm getting a **syntax error** and I don't know what it is. My database is mysql and my query currently looks like this:

```
$sql = "SELECT 
    users.username,
    posts.post,
    posts.time_stamp,
FROM users
INNER JOIN posts 
ON users.id = posts.user_id
INNER JOIN mentions
ON users.id = mentions.user_id
WHERE mentions.user_id = '$userid'
AND mentions.unread = 1
ORDER BY time_stamp DESC
";
```

What I want to happen is for the currently logged in user to go to a page called "mentions" and to get a list of the posts they were mentioned in and the username who mentioned them BUT ONLY if the mention is unread (i.e. is equal to 1) because later on that same page I will then change the displayed mentions 'unread' status to 0, which means it has been read.

I hope this makes sense! If you need more info on the db structure etc, shoot a comment and I will give you more info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have at least one syntax error in this line:

```
posts.time_stamp,
```

Remove the comma.  It is not needed before `from`.